# How can I open() and close() STDERR in Perl?

Tags: perl, stderr

Greetings ,

I can close the STDERR in perl using;

```
close(STDERR)
```

and after executing some logic , I want to open it back again.
How can I do it?

I tried

```
open(STDERR,">&STDERR");
```

and didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no way, you can't do this.
this is the standard unix security in force.

Comment: @J-16 SDiZ: "security"? how so?

Comment: What are you doing? There's probably a better way to do this than closing and re-opening STDERR?

Comment: Capture::Tiny may be of use. This allows you to conditionally capture STDOUT/STDERR and optionally process it later https://metacpan.org/module/Capture::Tiny

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why do you want to close STDERR?

You could put it aside...

```
open(FOO, ">/dev/null"); # or ">nul" on Windows
*TEMP = *STDERR;
*STDERR = *FOO;
... then
*STDERR = *TEMP;
```

Comment: File::Spec->devnull() will return the appropriate filename

Answer (score 10):

dup it first, then dup the dup to reopen it (error checking left as an exercise for the reader, though dealing with errors when STDERR is unavailable can be an exercise in frustration):

```
open(my $saveerr, ">&STDERR");
close(STDERR);
open(STDERR, ">&", $saveerr);
```

Note that when you close STDERR you free file descriptor 2; if you open another file and it gets file descriptor 2, any non-Perl libraries you are using may think that other file is stderr.

Answer (score 2):

STDERR is provided by the parent process. It is not necessarily some regular file, so you'd better keep it open unless you don't plan to write on it anymore. I'd avoid toying with the `tty` shell command and reopen /dev/pts/XX here, honnestly: that will only lead you into trouble

I guess what you may want to do is prevent some library to produce output on STDERR while it has been designed to do so. To do that, you'll need to keep the file open, but move it around in the list of filehandles. The system call  `new_file_descriptor = dup(old_file_descriptor)` do that in C, after which `dup2(some_fd,2)` to "activate" some file as stderr and `dup2(new_stderr_descriptor,2)` to "resume" to the real error output.

Closing one of the dup'd file descriptor *should* allow you to keep working with the other one, although I'd expect weird things to occur when using sockets, here. (beware, dig manpages and write test cases if needed).

Oh, and btw, the perlfunc manpage for `open` just show you the perl way to do those dups, although I must confess I don't quite fully understand the subtleties of that syntax:

```
open my $oldout, ">&STDOUT"     or die "Can't dup STDOUT: $!";
open OLDERR,     ">&", \*STDERR or die "Can't dup STDERR: $!";
# ...
```

Comment: credit goes to ysth for suggesting `dup`s, but I thought it could use a little more background and explanations.